# How do I change spellcheck dictionary in pidgin on windows?

Tags: windows, instant-messaging, pidgin

How do I change the spellchecker dictionary in pidgin on windows?

I have aspell with english and swedish installed. I would like to be able to switch between them at will.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd just like to add that **now** you can simply rightclick on the field where you input text when talking to someone and choose from Languages submenu on context menu.

Tested on Windows 7 with Pidgin 2.10.6.

Answer (score 6):

This was found by going onto pidgin help website

> **How do I change the language for the Highlight Misspelled words option?**
>   Pidgin currently only supports spell checking in your locale language. This is because gtkspell 2 does not offer a good way for us to know which dictionaries are available or to switch between them. This functionality has long been promised for gtkspell version 3, which has been delayed somewhat indefinitely. See [gtkspell.sf.net](http://gtkspell.sf.net/).
>   There is, however a simple plugin called [switchspell](http://plugins.guifications.org/trac/wiki/switchspell) that can change the spell check language on a per-buddy basis.

Comment: what if I have gtkspell but pidgin still doesn't highlight any words? And I don't see any `languages` in menu. update: found it, it seems with locale `C.utf8` it doesn't even show the languages menu... stupid.

Answer (score 0):

Pidgin does include this functionality, you can find documentation regarding how to swap between dictionaries and how to add new ones at the following links...

[How do I change the language for the Highlight Misspelled words option?](http://developer.pidgin.im/wiki/Using%20Pidgin#HowdoIchangethelanguagefortheHighlightMisspelledwordsoption)

[Is there a way to install Spell-checking support manually?](http://developer.pidgin.im/wiki/Installing%20Pidgin#manual_win32_spellcheck_installation)

Comment: Unfortunatly this relies on gtkspell, and that isn't ported to windows (that I know of)